# batch create symlinks of all files/folders in a directory

Tags: batch-file, symlink

I have a directory with many files and folders and I'd like to make symlinks of all files and folders in that directory to another folder but exclude one folder

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@echo off

    set source=c:\source\directory
    set target=c:\target\directory
    set exclude=DoNotLinkThisDirectory

    forfiles /P "%source%" /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE (if not @file==\"%exclude%\" mklink /d \"%target%\@file\" @path ) else ( mklink \"%target%\@file\" @path )"
```

EDIT - Updated to allow "easily" add of multiple excludes, using /G:file if findstr command filter the file/folder list

```
@echo off

    set "source=c:\source\directory"
    set "target=c:\target\directory"
    set "exclude=%temp%\exclude.txt"

    (
        rem exclude files/dires with these strings into full path
        echo .txt
        echo pipe.cmd

        rem escaped backslash and initial and final quotes to avoid partial matches
        echo "c:\\source\\directory\\something.txt"

        rem exclude thisNot file/directory from source directory
        echo "%source:\=\\%\\thisNot"

    )> "%exclude%"

    forfiles /P "%source%" /C "cmd /c (echo @path|findstr /i /v /g:"%exclude%" >nul) && if @isdir==TRUE (mklink /d \"%target%\\\"@file @path) else (mklink \"%target%\\\"@file @path)"

    del "%exclude%" > nul
```

Comment: would there be a way to easily add multiple excludes?

Comment: I used the simple version here to hardlink files. It seemed to work well, but occasionally gave strange error messages once it was finished, like `')"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`